# PowerShell script to copy same file from multiple folders of a server and paste in another server

Tags: powershell

I have a file with name `"file.config"` in multiple folders `(D:\Auth0\file.config, D:\Auth1\file.config, D:\Auth2\file.config.....)` of a server "S01". I want to copy this file from all the Auth folders and paste in another server using **PowerShell**.

All I came up with is below:

```
$Session = New-PSSession -ComputerName "S01" -Credential "domain\user"
Copy-Item "D:\Auth0\file.config" -Destination "\C:\Backups" -FromSession $Session
```

This script only copies the file from **Auth0** folder and pastes in the C drive of the same server. To copy from other folders, I have to change the folder name and run the script again.

I want to run the script which copy this file from all the Auth folders and pastes in another server.
Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you just run the `Copy-Item` command several times in your script?

```
$Session = New-PSSession -ComputerName "S01" -Credential "domain\user"
Copy-Item "D:\Auth0\file.config" -Destination "\C:\Backups" -FromSession $Session
Copy-Item "D:\Auth1\file.config" -Destination "\C:\Backups" -FromSession $Session
Copy-Item "D:\Auth2\file.config" -Destination "\C:\Backups" -FromSession $Session
```

Alright, if I understand you correctly this should work:

```
$DestinationSession = New-PSSession -ComputerName "S01" -Credential "domain\user"
# Is S01 you destination server? And from where are you running this script?
# See the difference between -ToSession and -FromSession
foreach($n in 1..1000)
{
    Copy-Item "D:\Auth$($n)\file.config" -Destination "C:\Backups" -ToSession $DestinationSession
}
```

Comment: There are around 1000 folders, so it will be a bit time consuming. I can run this, but this is going to paste in the same server. How can I paste in another server?

Comment: @Aish `Copy-Item "D:\Auth0\file.config" -Destination ('\\{0}\C$\Backups\' -f $svr) -FromSession $Session` where `$svr` is the target server name. You need the UNC path.

Comment: @Theo I used this: `Copy-Item "D:\Auth0\file.config" -Destination ('\\S02\C$\Backups\' -f $S02) -FromSession $Session` but it did not work.

Comment: @Aish No, that won't work of course. The whole meaning of the `{0}` is that it is replaced by one of the destination servers in the variable `$svr`. Have a look [here](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-f-operator.html) to see how that works

Comment: @Starlord, this solves part of my problem. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Theo, thanks, this solves the other part of my problem. Thank you so much.